How to access the output of a GitHub reusable action?
I'm attempting to make a reusable action that is capable of getting all the files of a certain type that were modified since the last push. The action works perfectly and its output is as follows (which includes a debug message for testing):
echo "DEBUG TEST: $FILTERED_PROJECTS"
echo "modified-files=$FILTERED_PROJECTS" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

DEBUG TEST outputs $FILTERED_PROJECTS correctly, which can be seen by the log:
DEBUG TEST: _test/folder_noskip/test1.txt,_test/folder_noskip/test2.txt

I then made a test workflow which is the following:
name: Get Modified Files

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Action Test
        id: action-test
        uses: user/get-files@v1-alpha
        with:
          commits-json: ${{ toJson(github.event.commits) }}
          git-branch: ${{ github.ref_name }}
          file-type: ".txt"
          file-ignore: ".fileignore"
          
      - name: Check result
        id: result-check
        run: |
          echo "Outputs: ${{ toJson(steps.action-test.outputs) }}"
          echo "Outputted files:"
          MODIFIED_FILES=$(echo ${{ steps.action-test.outputs.modified-files }} | tr ',' '\n')
          echo "$MODIFIED_FILES"
          echo "Raw: ${{ steps.action-test.outputs.modified-files }}"

The action-test step logs everything as intended, but result-check is just unable to get action-test's outputs, which can be seen by its logs:
Outputs: {}
Outputted files:

Raw: 

It could perhaps be a problem with how the reusable action outputs its data, so I re-ran the workflow with [DEBUG] messages on. The following was logged after the action ran its course:
##[debug]Set output modified-files = _test/folder_noskip/test1.txt,_test/folder_noskip/test2.txt

Therefore, it seems that the action is outputting properly but the result-check step is completely unable to fetch it.
Is there anything wrong with how I'm accessing the outputs? If not then what else is preventing the workflow from fetching the outputs properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Full action.yml:
name: "Get Modified Files"
description: "Fetches modified files based on the current event's commits and filters them."

inputs:
  commits-json:
    description: "The current event's commits in JSON format."
    required: true
  git-branch:
    description: "The branch to fetch for modified files."
    required: true
  file-type:
    description: "The file extension to look for."
    required: false
  file-ignore:
    description: "The file name that, if found, will skip a file in the output."
    required: false
    
outputs:
  modified-files:
    description: "A comma-separated list of modified files."

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Get modified files
      id: get-commit-files
      shell: bash
      run: |
        # Gets modified files from the event's commits
        echo -e "\033[36mFetching modified ${{ inputs.file-type }} files in all commits from the event...\033[0m"

        # Output the event's commits.
        COMMITS_COUNT=$(jq '. | length' <<EOF
        ${{ inputs.commits-json }}
        EOF
        )
        if [ -z "$COMMITS_COUNT" ] || [ "$COMMITS_COUNT" -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "::error::Unable to determine the amount of commits in the event."
          exit 1
        fi
        echo -e "\033[36mCommits in the event ($COMMITS_COUNT):\033[0m"
        jq -r '.[].id' <<EOF
        ${{ inputs.commits-json }}
        EOF

        # Ensure the repository is fully fetched to the correct depth
        git fetch --prune --unshallow || true
        git fetch origin "${{ inputs.git-branch }}" --depth="$((COMMITS_COUNT+1))" || true

        # Get all modified files
        PREVIOUS_SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD~$COMMITS_COUNT)
        CURRENT_SHA=$(jq -r '.[-1].id' <<EOF
        ${{ inputs.commits-json }}
        EOF
        )
        MODIFIED_PROJECTS=$(git diff --name-only $PREVIOUS_SHA..$CURRENT_SHA | grep "${{ inputs.file-type }}$" | sort | uniq || true)
        FILTERED_PROJECTS=""

        # Output modified files and filter by the file-ignore
        echo -e "\033[36mModified files:\033[0m"
        for project in $MODIFIED_PROJECTS; do
          PROJECT_DIR=$(dirname "$project")
          if [ -f "$PROJECT_DIR/${{ inputs.file-ignore }}" ]; then
            echo -e "\033[31m$project (skipped)\033[0m"
          else
            FILTERED_PROJECTS="$FILTERED_PROJECTS$project,"
            echo "$project"
          fi
        done
        FILTERED_PROJECTS=${FILTERED_PROJECTS%,}

        # Handle case where no files are modified
        if [ -z "$FILTERED_PROJECTS" ]; then
          echo -e "\033[33mNo modified ${{ inputs.file-type }} files found in the current event.\033[0m"
        fi
        
        echo "DEBUG TEST: $FILTERED_PROJECTS"
        echo "modified-files=$FILTERED_PROJECTS" >> $env.GITHUB_OUTPUT


can you share your composite  action.yml?

Sure! My apologies for not sharing it already.

Now see your comment and answer, this is was my suspect... glad you figured it out :)

After a more thorough research and experimentation, I found out that composite actions must have their output value explicitly declared, referencing the internal step that outputs it.
In this case, you only have to add value: ${{ steps.get-commit-files.outputs.modified-files }} in action.yml in the output declaration:
(...)
outputs:
  modified-files:
    description: "A comma-separated list of modified files."
    value: ${{ steps.get-commit-files.outputs.modified-files }}

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Get modified files
      id: get-commit-files
      shell: bash
      run: |
(...)
        echo "modified-files=$FILTERED_PROJECTS" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

With that, you will be able to retrieve its value correctly through ${{ steps.action-test.outputs.modified-files }}" in the action-test.yml file.
